# rel value get using onlick function

Tags: javascript

I want to get a rel value using `onlick event` and not with the jquery. I am having problem getting the rel value. Any help would be appreciated.

```
echo '<td><a href="#top" onclick="hf(event)" rel='.$row["id"].'></a></td>;
```

**js:**

```
function hf(e)
{
   var getid = $(this).attr('rel');
}
```

Comment: yes but this is not working for me. can u make it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

echo should be:

```
echo '<td><a href="#top" onclick="hf(this)" rel='.$row["id"].'></a></td>;
```

And your function can be:

```
function hf(e)
{
   var getid = e.rel; // or using jquery by: $(e).attr("rel");
}
```

Comment: thanks so much.i can't accept this answer before 6 mins. can u help me with one this. by doing this `onlick="this"` my `e.PrevenDefault()` now not working. any help?

Comment: use `onclick="this;event.preventDefault();"`

Comment: thanku for me this worked  `onclick="this,event.preventDefault()"`